# PHP select records for today from SQL Server 2008 datetime field

Tags: php, sql

If I use this code:

```
//Query and connect
$query4 = "SELECT jobno, cdate FROM delivery_comments;"?>
<?php $results4 = sqlsrv_query($connIntranet, $query4);?>
<?php echo $query4;?>

<table>
<?php //Loop through array and display results in table
while ($row4 = sqlsrv_fetch_array($results4)){
$date2 = $row4['cdate'];
$jobno2 = $row4['jobno'];
?>
<tr>
<td><?php echo $jobno2;?>, </td>
<td><?php echo date_format($date2, 'Y-m-d');?></td>
</tr>
<?php } ?>
</table>
```

I get these results:

```
87722,  2016-02-16
87704,  2016-02-16
87698,  2016-02-16
92334,  2016-02-16
92447,  2016-02-17
```

How do I write the WHERE clause so it only returns results for today

_____UPDATE_____

I have tried all of the options below and continue to get:

```
Warning: sqlsrv_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in C:\inetpub\wwwroot\portal2\short_delivery\delivery_short4.php on line 22
```

Here is my current code:

```
<?php
//Query and connect
$query4 = "SELECT jobno, cdate FROM delivery_comments WHERE date(cdate) = CURDATE()" ;
$results4 = sqlsrv_query($connIntranet, $query4);?>
<?php echo $query4;?>

<table>
<?php //Loop through array and display results in table
while ($row4 = sqlsrv_fetch_array($results4)){
$date2 = $row4['cdate'];
$jobno2 = $row4['jobno'];
?>
<tr>
<td><?php echo $jobno2;?>, </td>
<td><?php echo $date2;?></td>
</tr>
<?php } ?>
</table>
```

I have tried:

```
SELECT jobno, cdate FROM delivery_comments WHERE date(cdate) = CURDATE()
SELECT jobno, date(cdate) FROM delivery_comments where date(cdate) = 'CURDATE()'
SELECT jobno, cdate FROM delivery_comments where DATE_FORMAT(cdate,'%Y-%m-%d')=CURDATE()
```

These don't return an error but also no results

```
SELECT jobno, cdate FROM delivery_comments where cdate = cast(getdate() as date)
SELECT jobno, cdate FROM delivery_comments where cdate = GETDATE()
```

If I get rid of the where clause I get this error:

```
Catchable fatal error: Object of class DateTime could not be converted to string in C:\inetpub\wwwroot\portal2\short_delivery\delivery_short4.php on line 28
```

If I add the date_format back without the where clause it works showing all days:

Comment: `where cdate = cast(getdate() as date)`.

Answer (score 0):

You have to strip the time part from `cdate` because `2016-02-17 09:10:56` will not be equal to `2016-02-17`. Try this:

```
 "SELECT jobno, date(cdate) FROM delivery_comments where CONVERT(date,cdate)date() = CONVERT(date,GETDATE()) ;"
```

Use it like

```
<?php $query4 = "SELECT jobno, CONVERT(date,cdate) as cdate1 FROM delivery_comments where CONVERT(date,cdate) = CONVERT(date,GETDATE()) " ;?>
<?php $results4 = sqlsrv_query($connIntranet, $query4);
if(!$results4)
{
   print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true);
}
?>
<?php echo $query4;?>

<table>
<?php //Loop through array and display results in table
while ($row4 = sqlsrv_fetch_array($results4)){
$date2 = $row4['cdate1'];
$jobno2 = $row4['jobno'];
?>
<tr>
<td><?php echo $jobno2;?>, </td>
<td><?php echo $date2;?></td>
</tr>
<?php } ?>
</table>
```

Comment: I had tried that and get:SELECT jobno, cdate FROM delivery_comments WHERE date(cdate) = CURDATE() ; 
Warning: sqlsrv_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in C:\inetpub\wwwroot\portal2\short_delivery\delivery_short4.php on line 23

Comment: 'date' is not a recognized built-in function name

Answer (score 0):

MS SQL Server have provided a function for getting current date as `GETDATE()` so you can define your query as

```
"SELECT jobno, cdate FROM delivery_comments where cdate = GETDATE();"
```

Comment: This just returns no results

Comment: Try to remove ` date_format()` from your php code. and then check.

Answer (score 0):

You can get current date as `CURDATE()` function.
Modify your query as:

```
"SELECT jobno, cdate FROM delivery_comments where WHERE date(cdate) = CURDATE();"
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this query :

```
"SELECT jobno, cdate FROM delivery_comments where cdate = cast (GETDATE() as DATE);"
```